# MySQL query with codeigniter (active record)

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I am using following query in codeigniter using:

```
$this->db->select('products.id,
                   categories.name as cat_name, 
                   products.name as name,
                   products.product_image,
                   products.description,
                   products.price,
                   products.furl,
                   products.on_sale,
                   products.quantity_in_stock,
                   products.product_code,
                   products.rating_1,
                   products.rating_2,
                   products.rating_3,
                   products.rating_4,
                   products.rating_5,
                   products.rated_by,
                   products.discount,
                   ((products.rating_1+products.rating_2,
                     products.rating_3,
                     products.rating_4,
                     products.rating_5)/rated_by  as calc)
');
```

I get an error to check the sql syntax near calc. Please explain as to where and why the issue is.
p.s: I just wanted to use calc in order by clause like this:

```
$this->db->order_by('calc','desc');
$this->db->get();
```

UPDATE: This is what i get while executing this query:

```
Error Number: 1064
```

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as calc) FROM (`products`) JOIN `categories` ON `categories`.`id`=`products`.`ca' at line 1

Comment: Should it not be `products.rating_1+products.rating_2+products.rating_3+products.rating_4+products.rating_5)/rated_by as calc` . Try to print_r() the query ,and it should give you the formed SQL statement, easy for debugging.

Comment: try `$this->db->get('your_table_name');`

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to use aliases then you'll not want to have CodeIgnioter automatically add ticks around your column names as it will blow things up. Just set the second paramter of `select()` to `false` to turn off this behaviour:

```
$this->db->SELECT(  
                 'products.id,categories.name as cat_name,  
                  products.name as name,  
                  products.product_image,  
                  products.description,  
                  products.price,  
                  products.furl,  
                  products.on_sale,  
                  products.quantity_in_stock,  
                  products.product_code,  
                  products.rating_1,  
                  products.rating_2,  
                  products.rating_3,  
                  products.rating_4,  
                  products.rating_5,  
                  products.rated_by,  
                  products.discount,  
                  ((products.rating_1+products.rating_2,  
                    products.rating_3,products.rating_4,  
                    products.rating_5)/rated_by  as calc)', false)  ;
```

Comment: nopes not working...getting this error       "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as calc) FROM (`products`) JOIN `categories` ON `categories`.`id`=`products`.`ca' at line 1"

Answer (score 0):

yes you are correct @John

```
$this->db->select('products.id,categories.name as cat_name, products.name as name,products.product_image,products.description,products.price,products.furl,products.on_sale,products.quantity_in_stock,products.product_code,products.rating_1,products.rating_2,products.rating_3,products.rating_4,products.rating_5,products.rated_by,products.discount,((products.rating_1+products.rating_2,products.rating_3,products.rating_4,products.rating_5)/rated_by  as calc)', false)  ;
```

also worked for me